# "Missing return in a closure expected to return 'SomeType'" error in .map

Tags: swift, try-catch

I have the fallowing code:

```
struct AInt {
    var aInt: Int
}

struct ADouble {
    var aDouble: Double

    static func convert(aInt: AInt) throws -> ADouble {
        return ADouble(aDouble: Double(aInt.aInt))
    }
}

struct B {
    func doAction(aInts: [AInt]) throws -> [ADouble] {
        return aInts.map { aInt in
            do {
                try ADouble.convert(aInt)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    // ^^^ error here: Missing return in a closure expected to return 'ADouble'
    }
}

let aInts = [AInt(aInt: 2), AInt(aInt: 3)]
let b = B()
do {
    print(try b.doAction(aInts))
}
catch {}
```

When i'm trying to convert `[AInt]` to `[ADouble]` in `.map` using function that can `throw` error, i get this error:
`Missing return in a closure expected to return 'ADouble'`.
Well, i decided to add `return` statement in the end of `.map` like this:

```
return aInts.map { aInt in
    do {
        try ADouble.convert(aInt)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return ADouble(aDouble: 2.2)
}
```

Error disappear, but when i print `try b.doAction(aInts)` on same `aInts` array, i get this: `[ADouble(aDouble: 2.2), ADouble(aDouble: 2.2)]`, i.e. it prints my `ADouble(aDouble: 2.2)` that i set manually. Obviously, it's not what i want, so then i try to add `return` before `try ADouble.convert(aInt)` like this:

```
return aInts.map { aInt in
    do {
        return try ADouble.convert(aInt)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    return ADouble(aDouble: 2.2)
}
```

And now i get right result: `[ADouble(aDouble: 2.0), ADouble(aDouble: 3.0)]`. But this code still doesn't work without `return` statement in the end of the `.map`. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` method is declared as

```
@rethrows public func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

which means (if I understand it correctly) that the transform can
either return a value or throw an error (and this will be
forwarded to the caller).

This compiles and works as expected:

```
struct B {
    func doAction(aInts: [AInt]) throws -> [ADouble] {
        return try aInts.map { aInt in 
            return try ADouble.convert(aInt)
        }
    }
}
```

An error thrown from `ADouble.convert(aInt)` will be forwarded to
the caller of `map()` and from there to the caller of `doAction()`.